# Flutter. call a Future Builder with onpressed ElevatedButtom

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to validate a Login using a FutureBuilder calling from a onpressed button.

this is the ElevatedButton, where i call the function _validarLogin:

```
Widget _buttonLogin(){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:50.0, left: 50.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _validarLogin(),
        },
        child: Text('Ingresar', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 107, 152),
          shape: StadiumBorder(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20), 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is the FutureBuilder where I call the provider where is the api call, and send the data:

```
_validarLogin ()
  {
    return FutureBuilder (
      //initialData: [],
      future: loginProvider.validarLogin(usuario.text, password.text),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          print("Entro en el error");
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        {
          print("Entro en el waiting");
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if(snapshot.data!.size == 0)
        {
          print("Entro en el size");
          return Text('Esta vacio');  
        }

        print ("Esto hay en snapshotdata");
        print (snapshot.data);
        return Text('TODO OK');
      },
    );
  }
```

this is the future function i call from the future builder

```
Future<String> validarLogin(String email, String password) async {
    print ("El mail recibido es");
    print (email);
    print ("El pass recibido es");
    print (password);
    final value = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://serviciosweb.edesesa.com.ar/Usuarios.asmx/ValidarUsuario'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'mail': email,
        'password': password
      }),
    );
    if (value.statusCode == 200)
    {
      return value.body;
    }
    else
    {
      return value.statusCode.toString();
    }    
  }
```

Comment: How you are using `_validarLogin`, Can you include sample widget. And you can skip futureBuilder I think while it will call async method onPressed

Comment: I want to get the print at the last of _validarLogin, but it doesnt work, it doesnt execute it, when i press the button it call _validarLogin, the api is called but the futurebuild doesn show me anything. I also put prints before the snapshot controls but i doesnt execute.

Comment: FutureBuilder is a Widget and can not just be called in a function. You need to eg. navigate to another screen with the ElevatedButton and then show the FutureBuilder  on that screen.

Comment: How do i do to make a login controller? My intention is to use the futurebuilder to determinate if  i go the another main menu or if show an alert message